# Usage of "that" to specify quotation marks in speech

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Is it correct to use “that” in the sentence “I have watched the film that Star Wars.”

What I mean is: can I use “that” to specify the use of quotation marks, especially in speech?

Comment: No. But you could say *I have watched that Star Wars film.* Normally, there would be something that comes between *that* and *Star Wars*. But it can be left out, at least informally, simply in order to put an implied emphasis or familiarity (in some contexts even contempt) on the movie. But it wouldn't be formal usage, and I wouldn't do it unless you know exactly what doing it would convey.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea that "that" provides more details about the word before it.  For example, look at this very sentence!

> You have the right idea **that** "that" provides more details about the word before it

However, the details that "that" provides must be, itself, a complete thought.  In particular, it must include a verb.  Here, I'll *italicize* the verb.

> However, the details **that** "that" *provides* must be, itself, a complete thought.

Your sentence starts out well enough:

> I have watched the film

is grammatically correct (although, in American English, "movie" is preferred over "film").  But now you want to specify WHICH movie you have watched.  To simply state the name, don't use any additional words.  Just say the name.

> I have watched the movie "Star Wars".

This is grammatically correct, although a little clumsy.  ("I have seen Star Wars" is a lot better, but let's keep analyzing the grammar)  In order to use "that" in this sentence, you need a verb:

> I have watched the movie **that** *calls* itself "Star Wars".

Now it works.  This is a grammatically correct sentence now, and might even be a phrase used by a native speaker.  Note that this sentence is also extremely formal, almost pompous, and would not be used in most settings.  It would not be as formal if you were using "that" to provide a different kind of description.

> I have watched the movie **that** *has* lightsabers and jedi in it.

Answer (score 0):

In the English language (US), the majority of people will likely either say:

> *I have watched the Star Wars movie*

Or simply

> *I have watched Star Wars*

However, replacing `watched` with `seen` will likely be the preferred usage. Ultimately, you're looking for:

> *I have seen Star Wars*

The majority of people probably prefer `movie` over `film` - especially in relation to the genre for Star Wars. It is my opinion that `film` may be used in other genres, especially when dealing with non-fiction.